# Raise ClassNotFoundException even if I actually have this class

Tags: javac

this is my files:

```
.
└── src
    └── com
        └── subject
            └── math
                ├── Hi.class
                └── Hi.java
```

this is Hi.java:

```
package com.subject.math;

 public class Hi{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

when I try to run it, it raises:

```
$ java /Users/apple/Desktop/springt/javacTest/src/Hi.class

Error: Could not find or load main class.Users.apple.Desktop.springt.javacTest.src.Hi.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
/Users/apple/Desktop/springt/javacTest/src/Hi/class
```

I think I actually have this class file, but why JVM cannot find it? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solve it:

1. can not run a class with the full pathname
2. should not use `filename.class`,just with `filename`
3. go to `src`dir,run `java packname.classname`